# Using rxjs in the ES6 module system (in browser) without a module loader

Tags: javascript, rxjs, es6-modules

I have rxjs v6 from npm. I want to use it as part of a `import` using ES6 modules in the browser (Chrome v71)

From what I can see from here https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs and my general mucking about, it looks like I can't use it as part of an `import`.

Is there something small I can wrap it (thinking the CDN bundle) in to allow me to use it as part of the ES6 module system without the need for something like Webpack?

Comment: what do you mean? and what does wepack has to do with it? Even if you see in the doc you have posted, they show that you can do it even with es6 imports syntax: `import { range } from 'rxjs';
import { map, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';`. I use it every day with es6 module imports syntax

Comment: He may need this `import Rx from 'rxjs/Rx'`.

Comment: Related, presumably: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/4416

Comment: Sorry all, yes I meant in the browser. @cartant - that is exactly the issue I'm referring to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs#cdn

```
CDN
For CDN, you can use unpkg:

https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js

The global namespace for rxjs is rxjs:

const { range } = rxjs;
const { map, filter } = rxjs.operators;

range(1, 200).pipe(
  filter(x => x % 2 === 1),
  map(x => x + x)
).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```